# Listening to a website by a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make a simple chat application working over the internet.
My application first Posts the chat strings to a website. The web site will then send the data to the second person.

I have implemented the send phase, but don't know how I can receive data from the server.
What is the best way to listen to a website so that it is capable of receiving data at any time asynchronously?

Comment: Why not use an XMPP server/client ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use: [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)

It's even included in MVC 4